# Failed to create JVM.JVM Path

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jvm

[image: I am getting this error every time I am trying to Android Studio.]

I have tried all the solutions given on stackoverflow.com but the problem remains as it was.
I have tried the following:

1. created JAVA_HOME and JAVA_PATH and linked it to the correct directory.
2. uninstalling and reinstalling JDK and Android Studio several times.
3. deleted studio64.exe.vmoptions file from the bin directory of the Android Studio folder
4. tried other versions of JDK also

The most strange thing is that Android Studio used to run properly earlier, this problem came up recently and I am unable to carry forward my projects.

I would be thankful if anyone from this community gives me the apt and step by step method to solve this problem.

**EDIT**
[image: @m0skit0]

Comment: Is the path specified there correct?

Comment: Do you run out of space or memory by any chance?

Comment: @m0skit0 yes and even I have rechecked the path several times

Comment: @Koenigsberg no

Comment: Can you go to cmd and execute this: `dir "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre"`

Comment: @m0skit0 i have attached the screenshot